# Нужна запятая или нет? Необходимо мнение экспертов

Tags: пунктуация

«Кто бывал на высоте, знает, что там холодно...»... Интересует постановка запятой перед словом «знает»...

Answer (score 2):

Мнение экспертов здесь не требуется, потому что здесь всё очень просто. Два подлежащих, второе просто опущено, но оно подразумевается:
*Кто бывал на высоте, (**тот**) знает, что там холодно.*